# SignAPK - PEM file AND PK8 file

Tags: android, apk, sign, pem

What is PEM file & Pk8 file . Where can i find these for android apk. I need to use this to sign apk manually through SignApk.jar.

java -jar SignApk.jar certificate.pem key.pk8 PlatformOne.apk pf1.apk

This tool has integrated pem file & pk8 file. but i need my own private key signing.

Comment: Why dont you sign the apk directly from eclipse?

Comment: FYI: The correct extension should be .p8 as [specified in IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/pkcs8)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The whole procedure looks very well explained here [How to Sign Android APK or Zip Files](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-sign-apk-zip-files/)

Comment: Thank you Rover.. It is a great answer for my question :)

Comment: java -jar signapk.jar certificate.pem key.pk8 your-app.apk  your-signed-app.apk

OR

java -jar signapk.jar certificate.pem key.pk8 your-update.zip your-signed-update.zip

Comment: Link is broken and goes to what looks like a malware site?

Answer (score 3):

Go to your device rom. Here you will find `etc` named folder. Then open it and now you will find a folder named `security`. Open that now. You will find a zip file named `otacerts.zip`. Open that now and you will find your `pem` file

Comment: where is the key.pk8 file?

Comment: can't find the key.pk8 file anywhere

Answer (score 1):

The link in Rover Wanderer answer [How to Sign Android APK or Zip Files](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-sign-apk-zip-files/) details how to make and use `pem` and `pk8` files. I will add here the answer to unanswered part: *"What is PEM file & Pk8 file"*.

`pem` file is explained in good detail here (https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file). In couple of words `certificate.pem`is a container format file that in our example would include `public` certificate.

`pk8` is a format used to carry `private` certificate keypairs ([Wikipedia on PKCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS)).